# Trying to use event between two threads

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

I'm trying to make my first application where I use event to communicate between two threads. I don't understand working with delegates very well so I need advice how to finish my application and what are my mistakes (If any)?

I use two classes. Class 1, with two threads in it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class MyThreadTest : EventArgs
{
private string _threadOutput = "";
private bool _stopThreads = false;


            /// <summary>
            /// Thread 1: Loop continuously,
            /// Thread 1: Displays that we are in thread 1
            /// </summary>
            void DisplayThread1()
            {

                  while (_stopThreads == false)
                  {
                        Console.WriteLine("Display Thread 1");

                        // Assign the shared memory to a message about thread #1
                        _threadOutput = "Hello Thread1";


                        Thread.Sleep(1000);  // simulate a lot of processing 

                        // tell the user what thread we are in thread #1, and display shared memory
                        Console.WriteLine("Thread 1 Output --> {0}", _threadOutput);



                  }
            }



            /// <summary>
            /// Thread 2: Loop continuously,
            /// Thread 2: Displays that we are in thread 2
            /// </summary>
            void DisplayThread2()
            {
                  while (_stopThreads == false)
                  {
                    Console.WriteLine("Display Thread 2");


                   // Assign the shared memory to a message about thread #2
                    _threadOutput = "Hello Thread2";


                    Thread.Sleep(1000);  // simulate a lot of processing

                   // tell the user we are in thread #2
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread 2 Output --> {0}", _threadOutput);


                  }
            }



            void CreateThreads()
            {
                // construct two threads for our demonstration;
                Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DisplayThread1));
                Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DisplayThread2));

                // start them
                thread1.Start();
                thread2.Start();
            }
            public static void Main()
            {
                MyThreadTest StartMultiThreads = new MyThreadTest();
                StartMultiThreads.CreateThreads();
            }
}
```

I know there is some extra code but generally my goal is to simulate two threads.

The second class where I try to implement my delegate and eventually use a custom event for sending a message from the first thread to the second (at lest this is my final goal) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

   class Class1
   {
       public delegate void ShowMyMessage(object sender, EventArgs e);
       public event ShowMyMessage ShowIt;

       // Invoke the ShowIt event; called whenever I like it :)
       protected virtual void OnShowIt(EventArgs e)
       {
           if (ShowIt != null)
               ShowIt(this, e);
       }
   }

   class EventListener
   {
       private Class1 msg;

       public EventListener(Class1 msg)
       {
           Class1 Message = msg;
           // Add "ListChanged" to the Changed event on "List".
           Message.ShowIt += new ShowMyMessage(MessageShowIt);
       }

       // This will be called whenever the list changes.
       private void ListChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("This is called when the event fires.");
       }
   }
```

I know it's not just a stupid mistake, but I need to know if this is the way to create an event and how I can finish successfully my job?

Comment: What is the use of the first piece of code? It seems unrelated to the question. I think you should remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you subscribe to an event you provide information about the method and the instance of an object. But not about a thread.

Events are always handled on the same thread where they were raised. Synchronously.

So events are not a mechanism to communicate between threads.

Comment: +1 but could be improved by suggesting an alternative that Would work

Comment: I'm just trying things so the first part of my code is just for creating the two separate threads. What I want to achieve is to simulate firing and handling event between two threads. It would be enough just to fire the event at the first thread and to get something like `The event was fired` at the second.

Comment: Like I said, events are not the right tool for this. You can look up "Producer/Consumer pattern" for an alternative.